# Problem accessing directives inside TypeInterceptor using HotChocolate v14

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I am trying to access the directives of each field's type of intercepted types using HotChocolate v14.

Why am I getting TypeInitializationException when trying to access ObjectType's Directives in my TypeInterceptor.OnAfterCompleteName?

I also tried OnAfterCompleteType but the same happens.

```
internal sealed class ZajilTypeInterceptor : TypeInterceptor
{
    public override void OnAfterCompleteName(ITypeCompletionContext cc, DefinitionBase td)
    {
        if (!cc.IsIntrospectionType && td is ObjectTypeDefinition otd)
        {
            foreach (var f in otd.Fields)
            {
                if (!f.IsIntrospectionField)
                {
                    var ft = cc.GetType<IType>(f.Type!);
                    var ds = ft switch
                    {
                        IObjectType fot => fot.Directives, // TypeInitializationException is thrown here.
                        NonNullType fnnt
                            => fnnt.InnerType() is IObjectType fot ? fot.Directives : null, // TypeInitializationException is thrown here.
                        _ => null
                    };
                    var ad = ds?.Where(d => d.Type.Name == "aggregate").SingleOrDefault();

                    if (ad is not null)
                    {
                        f.PureResolver = _ => new Dictionary<string, object?> { { "id", "test" } };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        f.PureResolver = rc => rc.Parent<IDictionary<string, object?>>()[f.Name];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test source with test schema also:

```
using HotChocolate;
using HotChocolate.Execution;
using Xunit;
using Zajil;

namespace LibraryTests;

public sealed class ExtensionsTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void AddZajil_AddsFieldResolvers()
    {
        var sd = """
          directive @aggregate on OBJECT

          type Query {
            test: Test
          }

          type Test @aggregate {
            id: String!
          }
          """;
        var s = SchemaBuilder.New().AddDocumentFromString(sd).AddZajil().Create();
    }
}
```